# How to perfectly center "stacked" columns in mobile/tablet form

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, multiple-columns

I went to put two columns into my website. Everything is looking good so far, now I want it to be perfectly centered when it is in mobile/tablet. I got the 2 column from w3schools.com here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp. I was able to make it switch from two columns to stacking on top of each other in mobile and tablet form. Now I noticed another problem.

**I want the text to be perfectly centered and whenever you re-sized the browser the image will stay centered and the text will be move down to the next line when you resize it.** Because I noticed on my phone, you can still move to the right a little bit when you are scrolling so I don't want to have to move to the right in mobile, I just want it straight down in a perfectly stacked item with no scrolling to the right. Kind of like wrap text when used in microsoft excel or word.

**When you run the code snippet, you will notice that a bottom "sideway" scrollbar shows and I don't want to scroll sideway, I want to scroll vertically down.** How do I fix that? I tried flex, I tried float off, I am lost here, help me! I am unsure of what to do here.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.steveJobs {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
}

.billGates {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.column {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .billGates {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">


  <div class="column">
    <p>"A lot of companies have chosen to downsize, and maybe that was the right thing for them. We chose a different path. Our belief was that if we kept putting great products in front of customers, they would continue to open their wallets."</p>
    <img src="https://img.washingtonpost.com/rf/image_480w/2010-2019/WashingtonPost/2015/08/31/Weekend/Images/wk-steve0904-4.jpg?uuid=x2flXFAgEeWMGQtoJapKOg" alt="Steve Jobs" class="steveJobs">
  </div>


  <div class="column">
    <p>"The world won't care about your self-esteem. The world will expect you to accomplish something BEFORE you feel good about yourself."</p>
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/988775660163252226/XpgonN0X_400x400.jpg" alt="Bill Gates" class="billGates">
  </div>


</div>    <!-- End of row div -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parent row div *display* to *flex* and then the *flex-flow* (composed of the flex direction and if it can wrap or nowrap) to *row wrap*. 
It will now occupy 100% of the width with the two columns side by side in a row until it reaches the break point and then they will be one above the other in a column.

Add this to the start of the css file and it should work:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.steveJobs {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
}

.billGates {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .billGates {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">


  <div class="column">
    <p>"A lot of companies have chosen to downsize, and maybe that was the right thing for them. We chose a different path. Our belief was that if we kept putting great products in front of customers, they would continue to open their wallets."</p>
    <img src="https://img.washingtonpost.com/rf/image_480w/2010-2019/WashingtonPost/2015/08/31/Weekend/Images/wk-steve0904-4.jpg?uuid=x2flXFAgEeWMGQtoJapKOg" alt="Steve Jobs" class="steveJobs">
  </div>


  <div class="column">
    <p>"The world won't care about your self-esteem. The world will expect you to accomplish something BEFORE you feel good about yourself."</p>
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/988775660163252226/XpgonN0X_400x400.jpg" alt="Bill Gates" class="billGates">
  </div>


</div>
<!-- End of row div -->
```

I also recommend you take some time to read more about CSS flex at:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
and specifically about flex flow:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-flow.asp

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to your problem would be setting `box-sizing: border-box` in `.column`.

Comment: What does (box-sizing: border-box) does if I may ask.

Comment: In this case, when you set `width: 100%` along with a padding, the padding isn't taken into consideration and that's why you have the horizontal overflow. By setting `box-sizing: border-box`, everything within the border (and the border) is taken into account.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I will be using this one since it flows more smoothly in my website.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help! Be sure to read the property's documentation for a fuller insight into its workings 

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the help!

Comment: My pleasure, @Azazel.